# How to break down a string into separate lines in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery, split, unnest

My BigQuery table contains a String column:

```
WITH
  food_thoughts AS (
    SELECT 1 as id, 'I want a kebab' AS thought UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Pizza is delicious' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'All you can eat French fries!'
  )
SELECT * FROM food_thoughts
```

| id | thought |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | I want a kebab |
| 2 | Pizza is delicious |
| 3 | All you can eat French fries! |

I want to isolate each word of each sentence into a dedicated cell and match it to the other columns. How can I achieve this using a BigQuery command?

The expected output is:

| id | word |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | I |
| 1 | want |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | kebab |
| 2 | Pizza |
| 2 | is |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | fries! |

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following BigQuery code:

```
SELECT food_thoughts.id, word
FROM food_thoughts, unnest(split(thought, ' ')) as word
```

1. split your String into an Array of words with the `split` function
2. create a new table with the `unnest` `FROM` operator (documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest_operator)) and an alias
3. refer to this alias to gather all informations needed in the `SELECT` statement